# Using django select_for_update for not updating but creating new records

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, transactions

I am using `Django==2.2` and trying to create some new records for an object in django only if an upper limit is not reached. I was checking with

```
unused_count = Account.objects.filter(field1__isnull=True, field2__isnull=True).count()
vacancies = UPPER_LIMIT - unused_count

if vacancies > 0:
    *create (vacancies) new accounts here*
```

however we faced a case where this is not being respected and double the max limit accounts got created, and most probably seems like a concurrency issue.

Just wanted to confirm that using

```
unused_count = Account.objects.select_for_update().filter(field1__isnull=True, field2__isnull=True).count()
```

will suffice and prevent this issue or not?

The whole method is wrapped in

```
@transaction.atomic
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're actually using a DB that supports `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, I think the issue is that the `count()` evaluates the queryset.

According to the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) `select_for_update` should be used to return a queryset that you then iterate over in an atomic transaction.

You're not doing this, you're evaluating the queryset immediately by using `count`. And even if the entire thing is wrapped in `transaction.atomic` I think this is likely your issue - since the qs is evaluated immediately, another session can then come along and select the same records, meaning you have 2 things doing the same thing at the same time, which is how you managed to get too many records.

I'm not 100% sure this will work, but try this ...

```
unused_qs = Account.objects.filter(field1__isnull=True, field2__isnull=True)

with transaction.atomic():
    if UPPER_LIMIT - unused_qs.count() > 0:
        *create (vacancies) new accounts here*
```

This puts the evaluation of the qs inside the atomic transaction along with the  record creation.

(If this doesn't work, let me know and I'll either remove or refine this answer depending on what happens ...)